# In Power bi Date slicer can we only show the end of month dates instead of showing all the dates?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a report where I have sales data for end of every month. When I see the data in drop down ,I can see the end of month date , but when I have used slicer it shows the entire date range and not only the last day of the month. Is there any way in slicer through which I can just limit the date, so that only last day of month will be shown in slicer ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dates table with a date field (named Date, in this case), you could add a column with this code: Table.AddColumn(PreviousStep, "EndOfMonth", each Date.EndOfMonth([Date]), type date)